# will this system work? hi power led

Tags: led, led-driver

Well doing this for my fish tank and i need some tips and advise.
The idea is to use laptop charger for power. 19v 4.7amp 90w.
Will use 25 leds that operates at 3.7v and 700mah and parallel em doing so in
5 strings and each string will have 5 leds and one resistor of 1 ohms. 
So the question is will this system fly and will i be able to use dimmer or is it just on off system? 
The system will be mounted on alu and have cooling fans and heat past. 
Ty 4 help and its my first build.

Comment: Is the 700ma spec a maximum pulse current or continuous?  Is "each" LED forward voltage 3.7v ? Could you show us a diagram of your proposed hookup?

Comment: 1 Ohm series resistance seems not enough to effectively change a voltage source into a current source. I would suggest having fewer LEDs per string. The other concern I have is for the fish. These LEDs will be extremely bright and they might not appreciate that.

Comment: It's not a street, edit Your post to "normal" language.

Comment: DC Forward Voltage:3.6V~3.8V Forward Current: 700mA. Is what I get from manufacture on specs. And I was planning to build it like whatrogue drew up.

Comment: Was thinking to use a dimmer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be suggesting 5 LED strings connected as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUXfl2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is not a good idea. Neither the 19 volts nor the 3.7 volts are precisely determined. For instance, if you happen to get a batch of LEDs with 3.6 volt drops, your current will rise to 1 amp, which may well kill the LEDs. Likewise, if the supply puts out 19.5 you'll have the same problem, and since the supply can nominally put out 4.7 amps, this is a real possibility. Finally, for a given current LED voltage drops with increasing temperature, so thermal runaway is a possibility. That is, the LEDs get hot, so they drop less voltage, which means more current and they get even hotter, etc.

I'd recommend 6 strings of 4 LEDs, and about an 8 to 10 ohm resistor for each string. Then the current in the LEDs will be much less sensitive to voltage variations. Note that the resistors will need to be about 3 watts or more.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. Will see if I can do it 6 strings and higher resister.